# Bulk price updates in Magento ver. 1.9.3.1

Tags: price

I'm looking to do a mass price update, not by a set percentage and wondered what the easiest way to achieve this is.
obviously without possible data entry on csv file and re import.

Answer (score 1):

For editing product prices through an external `.csv` file please do the following:

Open the Magento admin panel

> Go to “System > Import/Export > Profiles”

3. Use the “Add New Profile” button
4. Let’s create a new export profile
5. There is no need to export all product details. Let’s export only the product SKU and price fields.
6. Save the changes
7. Then use the “Run Profile” button
8. Now the .csv file with exported data is stored in the “`var > export`” folder on your server
9. Download the file and open it with Dreamweaver or Microsoft Excel. You will see the products’ SKU and prices that you can change
10. After you changed the file, you need to import it back. To do this, you need to create a new import profile
11. Save the changes and run the profile.

That's it.

Comment: would this not wipe the other product data out when re importing?

Answer (score 0):

You can update it easily via a simple PHP script + CSV file.
Here are the FREE scripts for Magento 1 & Magento 2 respectively:

- https://blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/
- https://blog.magepsycho.com/magento2-fastest-way-import-update-product-prices-bulk/